# The bounty does not disappear

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I paid a bounty collector hoping that after that I can go to the city of Markarth without the guards attacking me. But they still do. Or they try to take me to jail. And if I kill someone in there my bounty increases as if it's the first time I'm doing something wrong in there. Is it a glitch? Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: another dovahkiin got conned by the bounty collector, easy marks ;)

Comment: Who was the bounty collector, where were they?

Comment: I don't remember :)) It's been a while since I paid him. He was somewhete around Markarth anyway

Comment: Looks like the posted answers haven't solved your problem. I did some googling, and it looks like a number of people have had this issue, in Markarth specifically. Some of them encountered it after the quest where you break out of the mine, as a bug. What did you do to earn the bounty?

Answer (score 3):

[The bounty collector has to travel back all the way to the corresponding city (in this case, Markath) to deliver the bounty.](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Bounty_Collector#Trivia)

If you fast-travelled to Markath right after paying him, odds are, you still have that bount on your head. And committing more crimes means you still have one right now.

Otherwise, it could also be a bug.

Comment: I didn't fast travel :)) I haven't been there for a while actually,two weeks to be more precise. Well, I still can't escape the bounty,and I don't want to go to jail. :))) I like my weapons soo I'll just try to not go in that city

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the bounty you paid off was for a different hold. Different holds have different bounties.

Comment: But that was the only hold where i had any kind of bounty:)))) And i was around Markarth when I paid. Far enough to protect myself from the guards but still around there

Answer (score 1):

Bribing a guard to overlook a crime does not make your bounty go away. If you want to get rid of your bounty, you'll have to pay it off, use your position as Thane or Thieves Guild member to ignore the bounty, or serve jail time.

Comment: He said be paid the bounty collector, that is supposed to make your bounty go away.

Comment: @Riley And given the results, I'm guessing he meant bribe instead of paying a bounty.

Comment: No I did not bribe any guard. I paid a bounty colector somewhere around Markarth. I can't remember exactly where.